# How to pass information to a string outside a method?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to the Java language and have become a little stuck, I'm trying to pass a location to the `String Bob`.  I need to pass a `string` from `onLocationChanged` method, to the `String url` which outside of the method. I have created a `global variable`, but the `String bob` does not hold any data.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


String bob = "";

LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);}
    }
}

TextView tempTextView;
TextView dateTextView;
TextView weatherDescTextView;
TextView cityTextView;
ImageView weatherImageView;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tempTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempTextView);
    dateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
    weatherDescTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weatherDescTextView);
    cityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityTextView);

    weatherImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.weatherImageView);
    dateTextView.setText(getCurrentDate());

    // location

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

           // Log.i("Location", location.toString());
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

                if (listAddresses != null && listAddresses.size() > 0) {

                    //Log.i("PlaceInfo", listAddresses.get(0).toString());

                    if (listAddresses.get(0).getLocality() != null)
                    {
                        bob += listAddresses.get(0).getLocality() + " ";
                    }


                    Log.i("hello", bob.toString());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider ) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };


    String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +bob+ "&units=metric&appid=xxxx";
```

Answer (score 0):

`onLocationChanged` is evaluated **after** you compute `String url`.

Once you have an understanding of multithreading, you will understand this.

At the moment, your code would be no different  if you move `String url` to the very top of `onCreate`.

If you want the URL to be properly assigned, move it after `Log.i("hello"`, and even check your logs to make sure it's correct

Personally, I don't suggest Android as the platform from which you learn Java

Answer (score 0):

> i'm new to the Java language

My best piece of advice to you right now is to stop, put Android down, and go learn Java (or hell, get started with Kotlin) before trying to learn Android as well as you go. Android is complicated enough as is without trying to learn the language as well.

Anyway, as to your actual problem:

> I'm trying to pass a location to the String 'Bob'. I need to pass a string from 'onLocationChanged' method, to the String 'url' which outside of the method... I have created a 'global' variable, but the String 'bob' does not hold any data.

You're problem is that that `onLocationChanged` method is a *callback* that actually doesn't get invoked until much later than the point at which you are trying to set the URL variable (assuming you actually *register* the callback, which your code does not show).

In other words, you are providing a hook in to the system that says, "when you have the location, let me know", meanwhile your code continues. When system lets you know the location is back (your callback is invoked) it's up to you to use the new value do something with it (in your case, I assume, make a network request).

So you would move your logic to right after the line where you update `bob`.

Hope that helps.